# Changing the default python version of RStudio

Tags: python, r

In RStudio, using`library('PythonInR')`, and then using`PythonInR::pyConnect()`
it shows that the location of the python called is /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7,
however there is no such package in my mac because I've deleted it.
I just want to know how to change the default python path of RStudio when I use PythonInR?

Comment: have u tried any groups or google?

Answer (score 0):

[`PythonInR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PythonInR/PythonInR.pdf) has parameters that let you specify your `python` environment that you want to use with `R/R Studio` in a variety of ways -

```
library('PythonInR')
pyConnect(pythonExePath = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe", dllDir = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3", pythonHome = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3")`
```

**From the documentation**

> **Arguments**
>
> `pythonExePath` a character containing the path to
>   "python.exe" (e.g. "C:\Python27\python.exe")
>
> `dllDir` an optional
>   character giving the path to the dll file. Since the dll file is
>   normally in a system folder or in the same location as python.exe,
>   **this parameter is almost never needed**!
>
> `pythonHome` an optional
>   character giving the path to PYTHONHOME. On Windows by default
>   PYTHONHOME is the folder where python.exe is located, therefore **this
>   parameter is normally not needed**.
>
> `dllName` a character giving the name
>   of the dll file (e.g.d "python27.dll"). majorVersion an integer giving
>   the major Python version (e.g. 2 or 3).
>
> `pyArch` a character giving the
>   Python architecture, i.e. "32bit" or "64bit". useCstdout a logical
>   indicating if the C stdout should be used or the stout should be
>   redirected at a Python level.

**TL; DR**

Use `pythonExePath` to specify the `python` exe location and give it a go. Try subsequent parameters if things still don't work

Comment: thx. But I've already tried this method in another laptop of windows system and it did work. But it just could not work when applied to my macbook, it still connects to the default python path.

Comment: On Windows you can change the Python version when connecting to Python.

Comment: On Windows you can change the Python version when connecting to Python.
On Unix the Python version is fixed after the installation. 
This is a result using different linking paradigms. 
On Windows explicit linkage is used on Linux static linkage is used.

For you as Unix user this means you have to reinstall your PythonInR however you also need the correct development headers present.

On Debian 

Sys.setenv(USESPECIALPYTHONVERSION="python3")
install.packages("PythonInR")


is sufficient to change from Py 2 to Py 3 given that also the dev headers of Python 3 are installed.